# Loaded async_sinatra gem, but my program is not finding a method in it

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, webserver, sinatra, thin

The gem in question is [async_sinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra). I have it installed, and ran a bundle install also with it in the Gemfile, but I keep getting the same error:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'aget' for main:Object`

Anyway to help fix this?

Notes: I am running the latest Sinatra, and am using the Thin webserver, and running JRuby 1.6.7.

The example code that we are using is:

```
require 'sinatra/async'

class AsyncTest < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Async

  aget '/' do
    body "hello async"
  end
end

run AsyncTest.new
```

Comment: Did you require it in the app?

Comment: Yes, with `require "sinatra/async"`

Comment: How do you run the app? Try using `rackup myapp.ru`.

Comment: @padde if we do that, then it complains about undefined method `run` (and I would assume that means it's complaining about the `run AsyncTest.new` part).

Comment: try it without the 'new' maybe

Answer (score 0):

1. rename the file to `config.ru`
2. Make sure to `require 'sinatra'` at the top of the file
3. Run it with `rackup config.ru`

Works for me on OSX 10.7 with MRI 1.9.3p125, thin 1.3.1, sinatra 1.3.2 and async_sinatra 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say you need to [register the middleware](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra#synopsis) Perhaps that is the problem? 
Without that line, I'm afraid your app gets the methods in `Sinatra::Base` and none from the `async` part of the gem and so, `get` works and `aget` doesn't